# Do I need a "to" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> “May I recommend (to) you a group class to deal with your anger?”

Do I need the **to** there? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the entry for **give** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give), you will see that it can have two objects. This means that you can specify the recipient in two ways:

> Give the money to me -*recipient linked with preposition **to***
>   Give me the money - *recipient is an indirect object: no preposition required*

If you look at the entry for [recommend](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recommend), you will not see any reference to two objects: The only object is the information that you are providing. Although it is technically possible to insert an indirect object for any verb, most people use a preposition with **recommend**, and I advise you to do the same.

If you want to specify the recipient, you should therefore use the preposition **to**. Note that if the recipient is the person that you are talking to, it is not necessary to specify the recipient:

> May I recommend a group class to deal with your anger

For anybody else, you should use **to**:

> I recommended an anger management class **to** him
>   I recommended **to** him that he should take a group class to deal with his anger

Comment: I don't agree. The double object construction is generally available for ditransitive verbs in English, and doesn't need to be specified lexically: _He gave/owed/promised/showed me the money_. It is even available when a singly transitive verb has a benefactive indirect object added: _She baked me a cake_ = _She baked a cake for me_. It is true that the construction is less used with a longer verb, so "recommend _pronoun_ _article_" only occurs 30 times in the Now corpus, against 12797 for "show _pronoun_ _article_"; but it is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @ColinFine; fair comment. I have removed the **not correct** paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need it: this construction is generally available with ditransitive verbs.

> I gave the book to him = I gave him the book.
>
> She offered a drink to me = She offered me a drink.

So

> May I recommend a group class to you to deal with your anger = May I recommend you a group class to deal with your anger.

Having said that, the construction is much more frequent with short, common verbs like "give" and send" than with longer verbs such as "recommend". The NOW corpus has the following numbers of instances of the construction "*verb* *pronoun* *article*" with different verbs:

- *give* 199408
- *send* 29430
- *show* 12797
- *offer* 7439
- *sell* 1932
- *owe* 1853
- *read* 905
- *promise* 469
- *recommend* 30
- *demonstrate* 4

As you see, there are not many instances of "recommend" used in this way in the corpus.

Comment: Do you have any references about length being a determining factor?

Comment: No, and I may be wrong about that. It is a surmise, from my introspection.

Comment: germanic vs latin etymology could work. Northern European languages use VPA, but latin languages use PVA. *terms and conditions apply. As always.

Comment: I agree with Colins. I never heard people use "recommend me" or "demonstrate me", however " promise me" isn't that rare. Short verbs are popular with this construction.

Comment: @SovereignSun: English words of northern european origin tend to be short, for example go, do, get, take, like, owe, put, eat and all the short words in Colin's list apart from offer,  whereas words of latin origin tend to be longer. The last three in Colin's list are all from latin. So, is length the determining factor for VPA construction, or is etymology? Difficult to say.

Comment: @JavaLatte Yes, I understand but we tend to use those only in formal English. Would you hear someone say, *"Can you recommend me a good sci-fi book to read?"*

Comment: @SovereignSun: We all agree that people don't generally use **recommend** with an indirect object, whereas you do use **give** with an indirect object. What's at issue is the reason: is it because **give** is short, or is it because **give** comes from a language with the same indirect object structure as English? I certainly use **recommend** informally: I can't think of an informal word with the same meaning. I would, however, be much more likely to say "Can you recommend a good sci-fi book [for me]?"

Comment: @JavaLatte That's exactly the way it is. I'm from Russia but I read a lot of English books and try to communicate much and I notice that **"recommend me"**, **"promise me"** and other examples are mostly written and not spoken. Though. I bet you remember the quote from **Titanic** *"Promise me now, Rose, and never let go of that promise."*

Comment: @SovereignSun: with regard to "promise",I'm sure you are wrong. "Promise me ..." is very common in speech.